# Is muon muon annihilation already realised?

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles, accelerator-physics

As muon colliders do not yet exist, has muon-muon annihilation already been realized experimentally?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking if we have observed a muon and anti-muon annihilating, whether we have observed a high energy collision between two (anti)muons, or something else?

Comment: I am not aware that direct evidence for muon/anti-muon annihilation in a collider experiment exists for the reason that you mentioned,  but the inverse process, the creation of a muon/anti-muon pair is a standard process. I am not a theoretical physicist, but I remember seeing the calculation (at least in lowest order) as a standard student exercise in QFT books, so I would guess that it's not hard to estimate the cross sections.

Comment: I imagine the odds are pretty decent that the process is actually been recorded in some LHC event from one for the detector packages. But no one is looking for it there and so we probably don't know it.

Comment: The interesting fact of the muon collider is not the muon annihilation itself (which from the production process we know to be very similar to electron-positron annihilation), but the possibility to bend muonic beams in storage rings at much higher energies compared to what is feasible with electron machines, therefore achieving very high energy collisions between fundamental (as far as we know) particles.

Comment: Also note that setting up a muon collider experiment, based on two primary beams impinging on two face-to-face targets for the muon production, would actually be easy. But the low energy and collision rate obtained in this way wouldn't bring much (if not any) insight of high energy physics.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Mr. DarioP Based on your reply, 1) would it be possible to set up two muon beams to study the cross section, to obtain data for muon-antimuon cross section versus energy) the same as the case for electron-positron annihilation? I would not of course expect annihilation ratio to be 1:1 but would it be detectabe by existing equipment?

Comment: Dear John Rennie, thank you for the reply. I meant  whether muon and anti muon annihilation has been observed experimentally. Because no literature about cross section data found, like in electron-positron annihilation cross section data at different energies?  Would annihilation be possible to carry out in muon/antimuon? Would mesons, or end particles in general, created in such a collision be detected by existing equipment?

Comment: With respect to your question about my hypothetical apparatus: I think that a measure of cross section would be feasible, off course it won't probably be possible to go to interestingly high energies, but for those there are quite many theoretical estimations following the studies fro muon colliders. See for instance the paper from V. Barger, MADPH-98-1040 March 1998.

Answer (score 1):

The direct annihilation of a muon with an antimuon wouldn't be distinguishable from other processes in a collision between high-energy beams. A collider would generate a whole menagerie of complicated processes, much like the [Large Electron-Positron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Electron%E2%80%93Positron_Collider) did before its tunnel was repurposed by the LHC.

However, if the muon and antimuon first undergo an electromagnetic capture reaction and form [true muonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_muonium), then annihilation (a QED process) becomes much more likely than the weak decay of either muon.

My initial instinct was that production of true muonium would require cooled ensembles of muons and antimuons to interact with each other, as is done to produce muonic hydrogen or the electron-muon bound state (which is, confusingly, also known as muonium). However, Wikipedia links to [a 2019 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08458) predicting that true muonium should discoverable using the LHC Run 3 data set, which [will be collected](https://lhc-commissioning.web.cern.ch/schedule/LHC-long-term.htm) in the next three or four years.

Answer (score -1):

A muon and an anti muon can annihilate but not a muon and a muon. They are not antiparticles. Two muons could exchange energy and momentum between each other though.

Muon antimuon annihilations works like this where the muons annihilate into a Z boson and this Z boson decays to electron neutrino and an antielectron neutrino.

$\mathrm\mu^-+\mu^+=Z^0$

$\mathrm\ Z^0=\nu_e+\bar{v_e} $